Typewriter effect not working RenderHtml component (React - Native)
I have chat based app where i am getting response in html formate i want to render it with typewriter effect. I am using below packages for typewriter and render html
'react-native-typewriter' for typewriter and react-native-render-html for rending html content.
Typewriter effect is not working please find code snippet below.
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html';
import TypeWriter from 'react-native-typewriter';


export default function App() {
    return (
        <TypeWriter typing={1}
        onTypingEnd={() => console.log('logg')}
        minDelay={1}
        maxDelay={1}
        >
            <RenderHtml
              source={{ html:'<p>hi i am rendering html</p>'}}
            />
        </TypeWriter>
}

I have tried multiple approach to render it but didn't work out. what i want is to render html content with typewriting effect in react native. it would be great if someone can help me out.

TypeWriter is a wrapper for Text component, so it doesn't work with html.

thanks @user18309290 could you suggest another approach so i can render html with typewriter effect.

As TypeWriter is a wrapper for Text component so it can't work with HTML so i found another approach so we can give typewriter effect to html content.
I am calling printSentenceSet(result?.data?.id, resText).
const printSentenceSet = (id, sentence, speed = 50) => {
    let index = 0;
  
    let timer = setInterval(function() {
      const char = sentence[index];
      
      if (char === '<') {
        index = sentence.indexOf('>', index);  
      }
      setCompResObj(
        {
          [id]: sentence.slice(0, index)
        }
      )
      if (++index === sentence.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, speed);
  }

compResObj is an useState variable
<RenderHTML 
   contentWidth={width}
   tagsStyles={mixedStyle} 
   source={{html:compResObj[props.currentMessage._id]}} 
/>

